# Error when creating DB link

Tags: oracle

I created a db link in a procedure but it throws an error PLS - 00103 Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following. Can you please help

```
 create or replace procedure procedure1
 (fname IN emp.firstname%TYPE,
 lname IN emp.lastname%TYPE, 
 number IN emp.deptno.value%TYPE,
 date IN emp.joineddate%TYPE,
 ) IS

begin

execute immediate('CREATE DATABASE LINK link1 CONNECT TO system IDENTIFIED BY "tiger" USING
   '(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
    (PROTOCOL=TCP)
    (HOST=171.54.65.11)
    (PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ADD)))'');
    insert into system.test@ADD values(fname, lname, number, date); 
    end;
```

Comment: Is your intention to create the database link and then use it in the next statement?  In the code you posted, you're using a different database link name.  Why would you want to create a database link dynamically in a procedure?  That implies that the procedure can only ever be called once (otherwise you'll get an error trying to create the database link since it will already exist).  Programmatically creating objects at runtime is strongly frowned upon.

Comment: yes Justin. Need to created the db link and insert the values

Comment: It looks to me like the INSERT statement should read `insert into system.test@LINK1 values(fname, lname, number, date)`.  That and the single-quotes before (DESCRIPTION and after SID=ADD))) should be doubled.  Share and enjoy.